# Optimal policy for expert selection (1-step bandit problem)

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

Suppose I have 3 expert who have provided answers to a binary classification problem. The experts have different (stationary) policies giving an (unknown) true $P_e(correct)$, and we also have differing amounts of evidence about this probability:

```
          correct wrong  N    %correct
expert 1:   80     20   100   80%
expert 2:    3      0    3    100%
expert 3:    9      1    10   90%
```

If we should make predictions based in the experts's performance how should be we choose predictions that maximize the the %correct given what we've seen the experts in order to make a decision

Clearly as $N \rightarrow \infty$ we should greedily chose the expert with the measured success. However, while $N$ is closer to zero, this policy puts a lot of weight on expert 2, about which we know very little.

What's the optimal strategy in the cases of uncertainty about the estimate on $P_e(correct)$

(This seems like a sub-case of the N-armed bandit problem, which additionally tackles the explore-exploit tradeoff. However, I haven't found references that describe 1-step optimal policies for bandit problems).